# Why are my values not being updated?

Tags: php, mysql, set, sql-update, where-clause

I have a simple, unsecured, local database that I'm learning with (yes still using MySQL for now) I can view my database rows in a table and click on an edit button which then displays the single record chosen with each column inside a text box to update and save. Here is my edit page.

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "XXXXXX", "XXXXXXX") or
die ("Check your connection.");
mysql_select_db("toner");
$quey1="select * from inventory where id ='".$id."'";
$result=mysql_query($quey1) or die(mysql_error());
?>
<html>
<form action="updateinfo.php" method="post">
<table>
<?php
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<tr>
  <td align="right">Partnumber:</td>
  <td align="left"><input type="text" name="partnumber" value="<?php echo $row['partnumber'];?>"/></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
  <td align="right">Description:</td>
  <td align="left"><input type="text" name="description" value="<?php echo $row['description'];?>"/></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
  <td align="right">Vendor:</td>
  <td align="left"><input type="text" name="vendor" value="<?php echo $row['vendor'];?>"/></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
  <td align="right">Price:</td>
  <td align="left"><input type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $row['price'];?>"/></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
  <td align="right">Quantity:</td>
  <td align="left"><input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $row['quantity'];?>"/></td>
</tr> 
</table>
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"/>
<input type="submit" value="Edit/Update Toner">
<?php
 }
?> 
</form>
</html>
```

Here is my UPDATED updateinfo

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","XXXXX","XXXXX") or die("Error: ".mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("toner");
$id =$_POST['id'];
$partnumber = $_POST['partnumber'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$vendor = $_POST['vendor'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$sql = "UPDATE inventory SET partnumber ='".$partnumber."',description ='".$description."',vendor ='".$vendor."',price ='".$price."',quantity ='".$quantity."' WHERE id ='".$id."'";
mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());
echo "Updated successfully";
header( "refresh:10;url=toner.php" );
?>
```

After adding a primary key I'm able to update the DB however $id = $_POST['id']; still gives an error, any assistance is appreciated. Thanks. Yes I'm aware its vulnerable to injection and that I should be using PDO or MySQLi but I'm still a beginner and this is where I've chosen to start learning. Thank you.

Comment: Learn using MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements, not using bad practises and outdated extensions which won't exist much monger

Comment: Are you getting values populated into form fields? why are you using while loop for retaining single value?

Comment: `(yes still using MySQL for now)` there's nothing wrong in using MySQL. I'd say using MySQL if the database is small or medium sized is a good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is because of `partnumber`,here you are again reseting the `partnumber` but the new one is not present in your database and because of that query does not update the new values.

```
$sql = "UPDATE inventory SET description ='".$description."',vendor ='".$vendor."',price ='".$price."',quantity ='".$quantity."' WHERE partnumber = '".$partnumber."'";
```

**Solution**

Don't again set the `partnumber` use it only in where clause.

Comment: For that use `inventory` table's primary key in where clause.

Comment: Most of the primary key is set on id column.

Comment: @DrewG So create primary key.

Comment: I'm using echo '<td><a href="editinfo.php?id=' . $row['partnumber'] . '">Edit</a>'; somewhere else, am I able to do something similar to allow the edit of partnumber?

Comment: @DrewG use this with your primary key like this `<td><a href="editinfo.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a>`

Comment: @DrewG you are sending id as a get parameter so use `$id =$_GET['id'];` instead of `$id =$_POST['id'];`.

Comment: That makes sense, however it throws up an undefined index error and does not update the database, thanks for all of your assistance, it is much appreciated and I am learning in the process!! Could my where clause be the issue? WHERE id ='".$id."'";

Comment: @DrewG can you update your code. I can't figure it out where is now problem.

Comment: @DrewG use one hidden field to store id `<input type="hidden" name="partnumber" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"/>` and use this to retrieve the id variable `$id =$_POST['id'];` in update page.